# Removing properties from array of objects, memory impact

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am processing a heavy array of objects on a node app, and at some point I want to remove two properties from all objects in the array.

At the same time I am measuring the node memory impact on `rss` (Residente Set Size).

What I am finding is that just the act of deleting them consumes a lot of memory.

Example, it's actually a lot bigger and with lots of objects. File size of json is 200MB.

```js
[
  {
   keep: 'foo',
   prop1: 'remove',
   prop2: 'remove'
  },...
]
```

This consumes the most from 500MB goes to 1000MB

```
const clean = original.map((obj) => {
  delete obj.prop1
  delete obj.prop2
  return obj
})
```

This also consumes a lot, also around 1000MB

```
original.forEach((obj) => {
  delete obj.prop1
  delete obj.prop2
})
```

This comsumes the least, goes to around 650MB

```
const clean = original.map(({ prop1, prop2, ...obj }) => obj)
```

But if I do not delete them at all then it does not consume anymore than the original 500MB. What is going on? Should not removing properties make the memory lighter?

Comment: because you are creating a second array. `map` creates a new array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map if you want to loop use `forEach`

Comment: The foreach, which is not creating another array, also uses a lot of memory thou

Comment: The `.map()` method produces an array of the same size so that should be fairly straight forward. The `.foreach()` method passes the entire array as a parameter - hence doubles up for that reason.

Comment: The first example is a `.map()` too, and it also doubles up

Comment: Try a for...of instead

Comment: @mplungjan, using `for...of` yields the same as `map` when doing the spread and the same as `forEach` when using the `delete`

Comment: That's because `for...of` also takes the entire data structure as a parameter - hence doubling up. If you use the `.map()` method, your best bet is to set the `original` variable to `null`. It will eventually get garbage collected and release that memory.

Comment: @RandyCasburn, could you please explain than as an answer with an example?

Comment: @Álvaro Did you test? https://leanylabs.com/blog/js-forEach-map-reduce-vs-for-for_of/

Comment: @mplungjan, I know, but when I check it against `rss` the gains are imperceptible

Comment: If you create a lot of objects that are identical in nature, the V8 Javascript engine may optimize their creation into a C-like data struct in memory that is far more efficient than a typical object with properties.  But, if you remove a property from one of these highly optimized objects, then it may lose its optimization and go back to the more typical object structure that works more like a dictionary with every property looked up by name (which is far less efficient).  So, probably your code is falling off an optimization path.  You could perhaps just set the property value to `undefined`.

Comment: The same is true of your array.  It may be an extremely efficient block of struct-like memory if it contains a bunch of identical (in structure) objects.  But, as soon as it doesn't contain all identical objects (as you start removing properties), that optimization is no longer in play and it resorts to a less efficient way of storing things.   This is the "optimization" game in Javascript where some small change can cause you to fall out of some optimized path, either drastically changing performance, memory use or both.

Answer (score 3):

You can use either of the `.map()` calls you provided (they are faster than `.forEach()`).

When you've completed the deletion, simply set the original variable to null. This will allow the JS engine to mark this variable for Garbage Collection and it will be removed from memory. You won't see the result immediately as we have no idea when GC will run and cannot control it. But the memory will be reclaimed very quickly.

Like this:

```
const clean = original.map((obj) => {
  delete obj.prop1
  delete obj.prop2
  return obj
})
original = null;
```

```
const clean = original.map(({ prop1, prop2, ...obj }) => obj);
original = null;
```

The issue here is that we as web devs don't have any control over memory consumption other than what I have proposed. Internally the V8 engine decides how things are put together in memory and all memory management issues are relegated to it.

Comment: This is odd, If I set the `original` to `null` as you recommened, I get `724.6 MB` of rss, If I don't I get `692.78 MB`. Then I did it again just to double check and this time adding `null` frees `20MB`

Comment: It sounds like you may be using references in your data structure. We don't know how your array of objects is constructed. If you've created the structure using references to objects rather than copies then it is possible those objects are still referenced in memory. As long as objects are referenced they will not be garbage collected and the memory will not be recovered - so you'll end up with _some_ duplicates due to this referencing.

Comment: Thanks, what would be an example of 'references in your data structure' so I can look for that in my code? the array of objects comes from a JSON file I read

Comment: "_the array of objects comes from a JSON file I read_" - then this is not a factor.

Comment: Please see the update to my answer

Comment: There's a lot going on that's hard to know about, including when GC runs.

Comment: @danh - Yep - my point exactly.

Comment: Now I see you said that. I didn't read carefully enough. The only thing I'd add is speculation about testing memory after a timeout.

Comment: @danh - I actually considered that, but most, not all, apps we write are very short lived (ms), so worrying about memory consumption should not be encouraged because its use is fleeting.

Comment: It's the first I've thought about this, but even setTimeout(f, 0) might have an effect, and if I wanted the most deterministic measurements, I'd probably leave several seconds for big hidden loops to finish.  To be clear: just speculating.

Answer (score 0):

Node uses the V8 engine, and V8 engine has two different internal representations of objects. A so called fast mode (default) and a slow mode (aka dictionary mode). When you delete a property from an object, the object gets converted to slow mode. What is significant in this case, is that the slow mode also uses more memory.

If possible, use `obj.prop1 = null` instead.

Read more: https://v8.dev/blog/fast-properties